# Zend Guard Loader failing to validate Application license

Tags: php, encoding, decode, centos6, zend-guard

I have an application with files encoded by zend. If i run "php -v" i get:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_long_arrays' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Directive 'register_long_arrays' is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:51:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

My /etc/php.ini contains:

```
[Zend]
zend_loader.license_path=/path/to/license.zl
zend_loader.obfuscation_level_support=3
```

I did not put "zend_extension=/path/to/ZendGuardLoader.so" in php.ini because its already loaded in /etc/php.d/zendguard.ini.

I have generated several licenses (still counting) for my application and my file.inc file returns the default invalid license error.
A summary of my file.inc file is as follows:

```
$lic_info = zend_loader_file_licensed();
If (!$lic_info){
$error=invalid license;
exit();
}
```

Please help guys 
Thanks!!.

Answer (score 0):

My configurations were correct, problem was the php-zendloader package which i was using was corrupted. It was resolved by getting a fresh copy of the files.